How can I fine-tune a GPT model to accurately handle rephrased or varied questions for my e-commerce chatbot?
I have an e-commerce website and want to integrate a custom chatbot. I’m using the OpenAI API with PHP code to communicate with a GPT model. However, when I fine-tuned the model, it only responds accurately when asked the exact questions from the training data. If the question is rephrased or asked in a slightly different way, it returns irrelevant information instead of the correct data from my website.
How can I fine-tune the model so it can handle varied or rephrased questions while still providing relevant information specific to my website's content?
Details:The chatbot should answer questions about the website's products.I am currently using PHP and OpenAI's API for integration.The model is fine-tuned but does not generalize well outside the exact trained examples.What steps should I take to improve the fine-tuning process or the model's ability to generalize for different phrasings?
